# Dynamic data drilldown in highcharts

Tags: graph, highcharts, drilldown

"list":[[[1425458096000,90.0],[1425460200000,109.0],[1425468600000,98.0],[1425480840000,103.0],[1425510900000,165.0]], [[1425458096000,90.0],[1425460200000,109.0],[1425468600000,98.0],[1425480840000,103.0],[1425510900000,165.0]]]
"dates":[1425456000000,1425456000000]
"averages":[113.0,114.0]

I am sending three arrays to highcharts. The list is array of date, value pair . I need to plot dates against the averages. And each index of list is drilldown data for respective dates. I need some help, how to get drilldown for this.Thank you

Comment: can  u please provide code or jsfiddle which you tried ? [please look into this for reference.](http://jsfiddle.net/7jevddL4/20/)

Comment: Check `drilldown.js` module for Highcharts - [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown). Also see [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown).

Comment: @TechnoCrat http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Vf3yT/    Here is my jsfiddle. The arrays will be dynamic . So I dont know how to plot the series and the drill down series dynamically

Comment: Check [async](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) demo.